# Rails axlsx gem load file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, axlsx

I need to load an existing xlsx file and edit it. All the example I found so far include creating a file from zero and editing it. I already have the file and I just want to edit it.

Anyone that done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem couple of weeks ago.
It is hard to believe, but you cannot do it with axlsx.

Its synopsis says: 
Axlsx is an Office Open XML Spreadsheet generator for the Ruby programming language. With Axlsx you can create excel worksheets ...

I would recommend to use roo gem instead.